# JetS3t vs AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-s3, jets3t, aws-java-sdk

I need to figure out between AWS SDK Java APIs and Jets3t APIs ? which is better in terms of throughput and performance?

I am assuming connection is not reliable so i may need to upload/download data in chunks.

There is API for multipart upload in JetS3t. But i am also looking for multipart download.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, I would go with [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).

I did the switch 6 months ago and so far I have a good experience. I can't answer you precisely in terms of throughput and performance but one thing that I can tell you is that it is less error prone. Sometimes, I experienced weird behaviours/bugs with Jets3t before switching to the AWS SDK.

One thing you should also consider is the support offered by both libraries. Jets3t are now rarely releasing new versions. Jets3t releases a new version about every 6 months or more, comparing to Amazon that releases a new version of their SDK about every 2 weeks. 
So if Amazon changes something or fix something in their services you are likely to profit more of it be using the Amazon API instead of the Jets3t API.

If you would have asked the same question 2 or 3 years ago my answer would have been different but now in my opinion the SDK from Amazon is mature enough and offers better support/stability than Jets3t.

Comment: Looking at release history now in 2015, Amazon's SDK continues to be far more actively maintained of the two libs: [aws-java-sdk](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk) vs [jets3t](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jets3t/jets3t)

Comment: Btw, a good point to note is that `aws-java-sdk-s3` dependency is enough for S3; `aws-java-sdk` will bring in tons of other stuff.

Comment: How do you configure the switch from jets3t to aws-sdk?